# How to rename files sequentially based on part of the file name

Tags: python

I am running into an issue trying to get a set of files renamed based on of the file name.  The original file format is:

**Rain.1699639200.Area4.png, Rain.1699639200.Area5.png, Rain.1699639200.Area6.png

Rain.1699747200.Area4.png, Rain.1699747200.Area5.png, Rain.1699747200.Area6.png...

Snow.1699639200.Area4.png, Snow.1699639200.Area5.png, Snow.1699639200.Area6.png

Snow.1699747200.Area4.png, Snow.1699747200.Area5.png, Snow.1699747200.Area6.png...**

In total there will be 12 groups of snow images and 12 groups of rain images.

I am trying to rename them to the following format:

**Rain.00-06.Area4.png, Rain.00-06.Area5.png, Rain.00-06.Area6.png

Rain.06-12.Area4.png, Rain.06-12.Area5.png, Rain.06-12.Area6.png...

Snow.00-06.Area4.png, Snow.00-06.Area5.png, Snow.00-06.Area6.png

Snow.06-12.Area4.png, Snow.06-12.Area5.png, Snow.06-12.Area6.png...**

The idea is to have the last image for the rain set of images to be Rain.66-72.Area*.png, and transition to Snow.00-06.Area*.png.  However, when it currently renames the files and sorts them it goes from Rain.66-72.Area*.png to Snow.72-78.Area*.png. It won't start over the with numbering part of the file name as I have shown.

Here is the snippet of code I've isolated the issue to:

```
 imageFile = glob.glob("%s/*.png"%dataDir)
 imageFile.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
 l = len(imageFile)
 j = 0
 k = 6
 m = 0
 n = 6
 p = 0
 q = 6
 for i in range(l):
    newimageName = imageFile[i]
    a, b, c, d = basename(newimageName).split('.')
    if a == "QPF*":
          if c == 'Area4':
              b = str(j)+"-"+str(k)
              os.rename(newimageName, dataDir + "/" + a + "." + b + "HR" + "." + c + "." + d)
              j += 6
              k += 6
          elif c == 'Area5':
                 b = str(m)+"-"+str(n)
                 os.rename(newimageName, dataDir + "/" + a + "." + b + "HR" + "." + c + "." + d)
                 m += 6
                 n += 6
          elif c == 'Area6':
                 b = str(p)+"-"+str(q)
                 os.rename(newimageName, dataDir + "/" + a + "." + b + "HR" + "." + c + "." + d)
                 p += 6
                 q += 6
    else:
            if c == 'Area4':
                b = str(j)+"-"+str(k)
                os.rename(newimageName, dataDir + "/" + a + "." + b + "HR" + "." + c + "." + d)
                j += 6
                k += 6
            elif c == 'Area5':
                  b = str(m)+"-"+str(n)
                  os.rename(newimageName, dataDir + "/" + a + "." + b + "HR" + "." + c + "." + d)
                  m += 6
                  n += 6
            elif c == 'Area6':
                  b = str(p)+"-"+str(q)
                  os.rename(newimageName, dataDir + "/" + a + "." + b + "HR" + "." + c + "." + d)
                  p += 6
                  q += 6
```

Comment: none of your filenames have `QPF*` in there name, why use very undescriptive variable names

Comment: none of your example result filenames have `HR` in there name

Comment: Sorry.  There is supposed to be HR in all of the filenames.  There is when I run the code...I just mistyped the filenames in my post.  In a previous version Rain was QPF* but I changed it.  Unfortunately, I can't edit this post.  It claims my code isn't properly formatted for this post, even after following the directions and tips to post code.

Comment: this means you are not showing us your latest attempt to code the problem

Comment: `j` and `k` are used for `Rain` and also for `Snow` as soon as you have seen `Rain-Area4` `j` and `k` are `+=6` when you see `Snow-Area4`, what you could do is reset `j..q` once when you see the first `Snow` image

Comment: are you 100% sure you have a `Snow` image for every `Rain` image, if not your numbering will be out of sync, better create a mapping from the `1699....` part to a `0-6` replace string, and loop over the files a second time

Comment: There is an equal number of Rain and Snow images when the images are renamed.  I will let you know if your answer works when I get back to work in a couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to create a mapping from timestamp to `0-6`

```py
import glob
import os
from os.path import basename

dataDir = '.'

imageFile = glob.glob("%s/*.png" % dataDir)

uniqueTime = set()
for name in imageFile:
    a, b, c, d = basename(name).split('.')
    uniqueTime.add(b)

uniqueTime = list(uniqueTime)
uniqueTime.sort()
mapping = {}
j,k = 0,6
for ut in uniqueTime:
    mapping[ut] = f'{j}-{k}'
    j,k = j+6, k+6

for name in imageFile:
    a, b, c, d = basename(name).split('.')
    os.rename(name, dataDir + "/" + a + "." + mapping[b] + "HR" + "." + c + "." + d)
```